# Build a PendingIntent with a back stack

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, back-stack

I have three activities (Home, Search, Destination), with which I could describe my UX flow. Home activity is my launcher activity, then its the search activity, which is happening to be the parent of Destination activity. So basically what I am trying to achieve is to have a notification, which starts the Destination activity and then when i press the back button I am supposed to go back to the Search activity and then to the Home, but the problem is that once I hit the back button from the Destination activity, the whole stack goes to the background...

In my manifest file, I`ve defined a parent activity for each of the child activities, like it is described here https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

This is how my code looks like, when building the pending intent:

```
 // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class);
 notificationIntent.putExtra("test", destination);

 //Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);

 notificationIntent.putExtra(DestinationAdapter.DESTINATION, destination);    
 // notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

 // Construct a task stack.
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

 // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
 //stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(testIntent);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notificationIntent);

 // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
 PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Could you please help me a bit? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your code should work, as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java

make sure you define parent activity in manifest where relevant:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```